# Changing ggplot line size in a time series

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have a time series with a variable that turns "on" at some point that I'm hoping to indicate by changing the line thickness. (I am already using color and linetype to indicate other variables in the plot.)

Unfortunately, setting size to the "status" variable, results in a discontinuity with the line between the last x when the variable is "FALSE" and the first x when the variable is "TRUE".

Reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1234)
data <- data.frame("x" = c(1:10),
                   "y1" = rnorm(10,mean = c(1:10)),
                   "y2" = .5*rnorm(10,mean = c(1:10)),
                   "status" = as.factor(c(rep(FALSE,7),rep(TRUE,3))))

ggplot(data,aes(x=x))+
  geom_line(aes(y=y1,linetype = "Y1",size = status))+
  geom_line(aes(y=y2, linetype = "Y2",size = status))+
  scale_size_manual(values = c("TRUE" = 1.5, "FALSE" = .5))
```

What results are lines from 1:7, and then another line from 8:10, with nothing connecting 7:8.:

[image: Plot with discontinuity between 7,8]

What I want is a continuous line between 1:10, with the thickness changing at 8:
[image: Plot with continuous lines and changing thickness at 8.]

Unfortunately, in my code itself, for each observation the variable turns "on" at any given time, so I can't just manually include multiple lines. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest approach would be to use `geom_segment` instead, since it can accommodate different aesthetic values at each segment:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=x))+
  geom_segment(aes(y=y1, yend = lead(y1), xend = lead(x),
                   linetype = "Y1",size = status))+
  geom_segment(aes(y=y2, yend = lead(y2), xend = lead(x),
                   linetype = "Y2",size = status))+
  scale_size_manual(values = c("TRUE" = 1.5, "FALSE" = .5))
```

[image]

EDIT - if you have multiple series, it will be simpler to reshape the data into longer format and pre-calculate those `lead` values. The code below has the same output but can be expanded for any number of series just by adjusting the range of columns named in `pivot_longer(cols = c(y1:y2)...`:

```
library(tidyverse) # for tidyr & dplyr
data %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = c(y1:y2), values_to = "y") %>%
  dplyr::group_by(name) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(next_y = lead(y), next_x = lead(x)) %>%

  ggplot(aes(x = x, xend = next_x, y = y, yend = next_y)) +
  geom_segment(aes(linetype = name, size = status))+
  scale_size_manual(values = c("TRUE" = 1.5, "FALSE" = .5))
```

Comment: geom_segment is perfect! It doesn't play nicely with the actual data I have (I have many different observations with values of y1 and y2), but I just ran a loop adding different geom_segments. Thank you!

Comment: See edit for suggestion on how to reshape before ggplot2 to accommodate multiple series more automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can have something like this:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=x))+
  geom_line(aes(y=y1,linetype = "Y1")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=y1,linetype = "Y1",size = status))+
  geom_line(aes(y=y2, linetype = "Y2"))+
  geom_line(aes(y=y2, linetype = "Y2",size = status))+
  scale_size_manual(values = c("TRUE" = 1.5, "FALSE" = .5))
```

[image]

I would prefer colors instead:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=x))+
  geom_line(aes(y=y1,linetype = "Y1"), color = "red", lwd = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y=y1,linetype = "Y1", color = status), lwd = 1.5)+
  geom_line(aes(y=y2, linetype = "Y2"), color = "blue", lwd = 1.5)+
  geom_line(aes(y=y2, linetype = "Y2", color = status), lwd = 1.5)+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "blue", "FALSE" = "red"))
```

[image]

The simplest way is to find the first appearance of TRUE in the data frame and having the corresponding row number as the end of first line and start of second line.

```
n <- match(TRUE, data$status)
nn <- nrow(data)

ggplot()+
  geom_line(data = data[1:n,], aes(x =x, y=y1,linetype = "Y1"), lwd = 1)+
  geom_line(data = data[1:n,],aes(x =x, y=y2, linetype = "Y2"), lwd = 1)+
  geom_line(data = data[n:nn,], aes(x =x, y=y1,linetype = "Y1"), lwd = 1.5)+
  geom_line(data = data[n:nn,],aes(x =x, y=y2, linetype = "Y2"), lwd = 1.5)+
  scale_size_manual(values = c("TRUE" = 1.5, "FALSE" = .5))
```

[image]